# Problems to configure Java for using in R version 3.5.0 and use rJava and coreNLP libraries

Tags: java, r, rstudio, stanford-nlp, rjava

A few days ago I downloaded an installed a new R version:

R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing" Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

and a new RStudio version:

Rstudio Version 1.1.423

However when I tried to load the rJava library I received this error message:

```
> library("rJava", 
lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object 
  '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/
  rJava.so':  
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/
  rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/
libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: 
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/
libs/rJava.so
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib: 
mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libclient.dylib 
: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I use a Mac and my OS system is:

OS X Sierra 10.12.6.

When I saw rJava did not work I installed the following java update:

java 8 update 171

and restarted the computer. Then I tried to use again rJava and coreNLP with the same error message.

So, I thought that maybe I needed an older version of java and installed java for  macOS 2017-001 which apparently installs the old Java 6 runtime for macOS 10.13 High Sierra, macOS 10.12 Sierra, macOS 10.11 El Capitan, macOS 10.10 Yosemite, macOS 10.9 Mavericks, macOS 10.8 Mountain Lion and macOS 10.7 Lion. 
I got this version from:

```
https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=es_ES
```

After installing this package I restarted the computer again, open Rstudio and tried again to load rJava and coreNLP with the same error message. After looking for a solution, I found a suggestion in the internet to run the following command line on the mac terminal:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

I did run the command and I got the following error message regarding a **jni.h** file:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Juan:~ juancarlos$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Password:
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java 
Java version     : 1.6.0_65
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : - 
L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries -ljvm
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   - 
I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
     ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

I have to say that I am not a systems or computer engineer and my knowledge regarding these issues is limited to the things I find in the internet. Could someone please help me to figure out what does this error message means and how can it be fixed to be able to use Java in R and run rJava and coreNLP?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I uninstalled the Java enviroment, rJava and coreNLP. Afterwards I reinstalled java version-8u171, the java development kit version jdk-8u171, rJava and coreNLP. 
Once I did that I loaded de rJava and CoreNLP libraries without problems.

I suggest to follow the instructions written in the following link from github:

https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX-10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)

In my case I think the problem was that the version of the java development kit installed in my Mac was too old and incompatible with rJava and coreNLP.